# "or" operator not working as expected in render method of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use "or" || operator in my render method of react like this (aim is to decide whether or not to show  element)

```
<div className="item-actions">
    {this.state.addedMovieTag.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
    }).length > 0 || this.state.addedPersonTag.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
    }).length > 0  &&  <span className="fa fa-edit" onClick={this.saveChanges.bind(this, item)}></span>}
    <span className="fa fa-trash"></span>
</div>
```

now consider following scenarios (aim is to decide whether or not to show )

scenario 1: (span not shown)

```
this.state.addedMovieTag.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
}).length === 0 
this.state.addedPersonTag.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
}).length === 0
```

scenario 2: (span shows - expected behaviour)

```
this.state.addedMovieTag.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
}).length === 1 
this.state.addedPersonTag.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
}).length === 0
```

scenario 3: (span shows - expected behaviour)

```
this.state.addedMovieTag.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
}).length === 2
this.state.addedPersonTag.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
}).length === 0
```

scenario 4: (span not shows up - UNEXPECTED behaviour)

```
this.state.addedMovieTag.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
}).length === 2
this.state.addedPersonTag.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
}).length === 1
```

Comment: Your expression is: `a || b || c && d`. So is `d` associated with `c`? Yes. So if `a` or `b` is true, it will return true. but if `c` is false, it will not render `d`. Only case when d is rendered is if `a` and `b` is false and `c` is true. Try `(a || b || c) && d` instead

Comment: Possibly some logical operator precedence fault where `a || b && c` is different from `(a || b) && c` (being the latter what you desire)? Also, I would recommend moving that logic out from the view and assign it to a variable so it leaves the view to rendering only with an easy-to-read simple logic e.g. `{hasContentToDisplay && <span ...>}`

Comment: @mathielo Thanks a lot. Rookie mistake from my side

Comment: A bit unrelated, but you may want to consider using the `.some()` function if you're checking for `length > 0` after a `filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:

`false && (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to false.

`true || (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to true.

So you should wrap all conditions into bracket and use `||`

```
<div className="item-actions">
    { (this.state.addedMovieTag.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
    }).length > 0 || this.state.addedPersonTag.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.trivia_id === item.id;
    }).length > 0 ) &&  <span className="fa fa-edit" onClick={this.saveChanges.bind(this, item)}></span>}
    <span className="fa fa-trash"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the short circuit evaluation ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical ) and could be simply fixed by placing the OR check in brackets.

You could try typing in browser console:

```
true || true && false //will return true
(true || true) && false //will return false
```